# subsection after table appears before

Tags: tables, sectioning

I have the following code:

```
\subsection{AAA}
This data was taken from RStudio's fclust packedge.

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Butterfly data - 3 clusters}

\begin{tabular}{
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l l
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l l
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l }
&\textbf{Python}  &        &  &      &  \textbf{R}   &      &  &        & \textbf{Spark}    &          \\
0.4374 & 0.2407 & 0.3217 &  & 0.44 & 0.24 & 0.32 &  & 0.3403 & 0.34034 & 0.319318 \\
0.1433 & 0.1004 & 0.7561 &  & 0.14 & 0.1  & 0.75 &  & 0.2194 & 0.21345 & 0.567114 \\
0.0292 & 0.0286 & 0.9421 &  & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.94 &  & 0.0861 & 0.08277 & 0.831062 \\
0.1056 & 0.1462 & 0.7481 &  & 0.1  & 0.14 & 0.75 &  & 0.2194 & 0.21345 & 0.567114 \\
0.0570 & 0.0418 & 0.9011 &  & 0.06 & 0.04 & 0.9  &  & 0.1490 & 0.14206 & 0.708855 \\
0.0006 & 0.0006 & 0.9986 &  & 0    & 0    & 1    &  & 0.0010 & 9.51E-0 & 0.998038 \\
0.0461 & 0.0595 & 0.8942 &  & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.9  &  & 0.1490 & 0.14206 & 0.708855 \\
0.0989 & 0.0943 & 0.8066 &  & 0.1  & 0.1  & 0.81 &  & 0.3724 & 0.32940 & 0.298178 \\
0.3253 & 0.2986 & 0.3759 &  & 0.31 & 0.31 & 0.38 &  & 0.1877 & 0.81202 & 1.93E-04 \\
0.4813 & 0.4052 & 0.1133 &  & 0.44 & 0.44 & 0.11 &  & 0.4457 & 0.50064 & 0.053554 \\
0.9905 & 0.0072 & 0.0022 &  & 0.98 & 0.01 & 0    &  & 0.4257 & 0.44637 & 0.127889 \\
0.5361 & 0.4188 & 0.0449 &  & 0.48 & 0.48 & 0.05 &  & 0.4313 & 4.57E-0 & 0.111201 \\
0.0246 & 0.9688 & 0.0065 &  & 0.01 & 0.98 & 0    &  & 0.4257 & 0.44637 & 0.127889 \\
0.8283 & 0.1217 & 0.0498 &  & 0.84 & 0.12 & 0.05 &  & 0.4032 & 0.41446 & 0.182285 \\
0.5068 & 0.4434 & 0.0496 &  & 0.48 & 0.48 & 0.05 &  & 0.4155 & 0.43226 & 0.152180 \\
0.1149 & 0.8418 & 0.0431 &  & 0.12 & 0.84 & 0.05 &  & 0.4032 & 0.41446 & 0.182285 \\
0.2429 & 0.4453 & 0.3116 &  & 0.24 & 0.44 & 0.32 &  & 0.3403 & 0.34034 & 0.319318
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{BBB}
```

but when I generate the code, I see:

AAA

BBB

table

How to make the order to be as the one in the code:

AAA

table

BBB

Comment: Just drop this dreadful `table` stuff and use `\captionof{table}{Your caption}` (requires `caption` package) -- this will prevent this `floating` which causes in many cases more problems than really needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [float package](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) with the placement specifier [H] to force the table into the position you want:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\subsection{AAA}
This data was taken from RStudio's fclust packedge.

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Butterfly data - 3 clusters}

\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
&\textbf{Python}  &        &  &      &  \textbf{R}   &      &  &        & \textbf{Spark}    &          \\
0.4374 & 0.2407 & 0.3217 &  & 0.44 & 0.24 & 0.32 &  & 0.3403 & 0.34034 & 0.319318 \\
0.1433 & 0.1004 & 0.7561 &  & 0.14 & 0.1  & 0.75 &  & 0.2194 & 0.21345 & 0.567114 \\
0.0292 & 0.0286 & 0.9421 &  & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.94 &  & 0.0861 & 0.08277 & 0.831062 \\
0.1056 & 0.1462 & 0.7481 &  & 0.1  & 0.14 & 0.75 &  & 0.2194 & 0.21345 & 0.567114 \\
0.0570 & 0.0418 & 0.9011 &  & 0.06 & 0.04 & 0.9  &  & 0.1490 & 0.14206 & 0.708855 \\
0.0006 & 0.0006 & 0.9986 &  & 0    & 0    & 1    &  & 0.0010 & 9.51E-0 & 0.998038 \\
0.0461 & 0.0595 & 0.8942 &  & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.9  &  & 0.1490 & 0.14206 & 0.708855 \\
0.0989 & 0.0943 & 0.8066 &  & 0.1  & 0.1  & 0.81 &  & 0.3724 & 0.32940 & 0.298178 \\
0.3253 & 0.2986 & 0.3759 &  & 0.31 & 0.31 & 0.38 &  & 0.1877 & 0.81202 & 1.93E-04 \\
0.4813 & 0.4052 & 0.1133 &  & 0.44 & 0.44 & 0.11 &  & 0.4457 & 0.50064 & 0.053554 \\
0.9905 & 0.0072 & 0.0022 &  & 0.98 & 0.01 & 0    &  & 0.4257 & 0.44637 & 0.127889 \\
0.5361 & 0.4188 & 0.0449 &  & 0.48 & 0.48 & 0.05 &  & 0.4313 & 4.57E-0 & 0.111201 \\
0.0246 & 0.9688 & 0.0065 &  & 0.01 & 0.98 & 0    &  & 0.4257 & 0.44637 & 0.127889 \\
0.8283 & 0.1217 & 0.0498 &  & 0.84 & 0.12 & 0.05 &  & 0.4032 & 0.41446 & 0.182285 \\
0.5068 & 0.4434 & 0.0496 &  & 0.48 & 0.48 & 0.05 &  & 0.4155 & 0.43226 & 0.152180 \\
0.1149 & 0.8418 & 0.0431 &  & 0.12 & 0.84 & 0.05 &  & 0.4032 & 0.41446 & 0.182285 \\
0.2429 & 0.4453 & 0.3116 &  & 0.24 & 0.44 & 0.32 &  & 0.3403 & 0.34034 & 0.319318
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{BBB}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

also I think you probably mean "RStudio's fclust package" not "packedge" `:)`.

Comment: worked perfectly, thats a lot